# System of equations. How to split a string to gain two matrices A and b in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a string like for example this (the number of variables and constants is not important):

```
> my_string <- "-x+2y+z=-1; x-3y-2z=-1; 3x-y-z=4"
```

I know how to obtain a `cbind(A, b)` matrix using replace and numeric functions...

```
#    [,1]   [,2]   [,3]    [,4]
# [1,] -1     2      1      -1
# [2,]  1    -3     -2      -1
# [3,]  3    -1     -1       4
```

...but have no idea how to automatically gain two matrices `A` and `b`

```
A
#    [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
# [1,]-1     2      1
# [2,] 1    -3     -2 
# [3,] 3    -1     -1  

b
#    [,1]   
# [1,]-1
# [2,]-1
# [3,] 4
```

It means how can I split this string on `=` to gain one matrix with numerical elements located before the equal sign and an other with elements which are located after it?

EDIT.
So far I made this:

```
my_string<-"-x+2y+z=-1; x-3y-2z=-1; 3x-y-z=4"    
my_string<-gsub('([[:punct:]]|\\s)([a-z])', '\\11\\2', my_string)   
my_string<-stringr::str_replace_all(my_string,"[a-z]"," ")    
my_string<-stringr::str_replace_all(my_string,"; ",";")    
my_string<-stringr::str_replace_all(my_string,"[-]","+-")       
my_string<-stringr::str_replace_all(my_string,"[+]"," ")    
my_string<-stringr::str_replace_all(my_string,"[=] ","=")    
my_string<-stringr::str_replace_all(my_string,"   ",",")    
my_string<-stringr::str_replace_all(my_string,"  ",",")    
my_string<-stringr::str_replace_all(my_string," ",",")    
my_string<-gsub("^,","",my_string)        
my_string <- strsplit(my_string, "=|;")
```

And I gained:

```
# "-1,2,1"  "-1"      "1,-3,-2" "-1"      "3,-1,-1" "4"
```

How to connect this strings?

```
> A <- "-1,2,1,1,-3,-2,3,-1,-1"
> b <- "-1,-1,4"
```

Comment: Regarding the question in the edit: `A <- read.table(text = sub(",$", "", my_string[[1]][c(TRUE, FALSE)]), sep = ",");
b <- as.numeric(my_string[[1]][c(FALSE, TRUE)])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some alternatives.  All can handle strings like `my_string` shown in the question but (3), (4) and (5) can also handle equations in which some of the variables are missing and the variables are out of order.  Only (4) hard codes the variable names but it is generalized in (5).

**1)** Insert 1 before any variable that has no numeric multiplier giving `s1`.  Then extract the variable names assuming they are on letter each and count the unique ones giving the number `n`.  Then extract the numbers, convert them to numeric and shape them into a matrix using `n`.  It is assumed that all three variables are present in each equation and that they are in the same order since that is the case in the question's example.

```
library(gsubfn)

my_string<-"-x+2y+z=-1; x-3y-2z=-1; 3x-y-z=4"
s1 <- gsub('(^|\\W)([a-z])', '\\11\\2', my_string) # from your prior question

n <- length(strapplyc(s1, "[a-z]", simplify = unique))
matrix(strapply(s1, "(-?\\d+)", as.numeric, simplify = c), n, byrow = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   -1    2    1   -1
[2,]    1   -3   -2   -1
[3,]    3   -1   -1    4
```

**2)** A variation is to split `s1` from above at semicolon giving `s2`.  Then use `strapply` to pick out the numbers giving `mat`.  Finally convert the numbers from character to numeric.

```
library(gsubfn)

s2 <- strsplit(s1, ";")

mat <- do.call("rbind", sapply(s2, strapply, "(-?\\d+)"))
matrix(as.numeric(mat), nrow(mat))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   -1    2    1   -1
[2,]    1   -3   -2   -1
[3,]    3   -1   -1    4
```

**3)** This alternative can handle missing variables such as in the example below where `y` is missing in the first equation.  `varnames` are the variable names. The `extr` function takes a variable name and extracts its coefficients or 0 if the variable does not appear.

```
library(gsubfn)

my_string2 <- "-x+z=-1; x-3y-2z=-1; 3x-y-z=4"
s1 <- gsub('(^|\\W)([a-z])', '\\11\\2', my_string2)
s2 <- strsplit(s1, ";")

varnames <- sort(strapplyc(s1, "[a-z]", simplify = unique))
extr <- function(x) 
  strapply(s2[[1]], paste0("-?\\d", x), ~ as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", x)), empty = 0)
A <- sapply(varnames, extr)
b <- as.numeric(sub(".*=", "", s2[[1]]))
```

giving:

```
> A
     x y z
[1,] 1 0 1
[2,] 1 3 2
[3,] 3 1 1
> b
[1] -1 -1  4
```

**4)** This one replaces `x` with `*c(1, 0, 0)`, `y` with `*c(0,1,0)` and `z` with `*c(0,0,1)` and the evaluates them to produce `A`.  It is particularly simple.  It can also handle equations in which not all variables are present. 
It assumes that the variables are `x`, `y` and `z` although it could be generalized.

```
my_string2 <- "-x+z=-1; x-3y-2z=-1; 3x-y-z=4"
s1 <- gsub('(^|\\W)([a-z])', '\\11\\2', my_string2)
s2 <- strsplit(s1, ";")
s <- sub("=.*", "", s2[[1]])
s <- gsub("x", "*c(1, 0, 0)", s)
s <- gsub("y", "*c(0, 1, 0)", s)
s <- gsub("z", "*c(0, 0, 1)", s)
A <- eval(parse(text = paste("rbind(", paste(s, collapse = ","), ")")))
b <- as.numeric(sub(".*=", "", s2[[1]]))
```

giving:

```
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -1    0    1
[2,]    1   -3   -2
[3,]    3   -1   -1
> b
[1] -1 -1  4
```

**5)** This is a generalized version of (4) where x, y and z are not hard coded.  It can handle unordered and missing variables.  We first get the variable names in `varnames`, split the input string giving `spl`, for the ith variable name replace it with a vector of 0's with 1 in the ith position giving `ss1`, insert `*` before any such vector prefixed by a digit giving `ss2`, remove `=` and everything after that and surround it with `cbind(...)` and evaluate it as an R expression giving `A`.  `b` is everything after `=` converted to numeric.

```
library(gsubfn)
my_string2 <- "-z+x=-1; x-3y-2z=-1; 3x-y-z=4"
ss0 <- my_string2
varnames <- sort(strapplyc(ss0, "[a-z]", simplify = unique))
spl <- strsplit(ss0, ";")[[1]]
ss1 <- gsubfn("[a-z]", x ~ (match(x, varnames) == seq_along(varnames))+0, spl)
ss2 <- gsub("(\\d)c", "\\1*c", ss1)
ss3 <- sub("=.*", "", ss2)
A <- eval(parse(text = paste("rbind(", paste(ss3, collapse = ","), ")")))
b <- as.numeric(sub(".*=", "", ss2))
```

giving:

```
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0   -1
[2,]    1   -3   -2
[3,]    3   -1   -1
> b
[1] -1 -1  4
```

Answer (score 3):

With base R only. A bit ugly, too many calls to `strsplit` and `*apply` functions.

```
my_string <- "-x+2y+z=-1; x-3y-2z=-1; 3x-y-z=4"

sp1 <- unlist(strsplit(my_string, ";"))
sp2 <- strsplit(sp1, "=")
b <- as.numeric(sapply(sp2, '[[', 2))
sp3 <- lapply(lapply(sp2, '[[', 1), function(s) gsub("([-+])([[:alpha:]])", "\\11\\2", s))
sp3 <- lapply(sp3, trimws)
sp3 <- lapply(sp3, function(s) sub("^([[:alpha:]])", "1\\1", s))
A <- do.call(rbind, lapply(sp3, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, "[[:alpha:]]")))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a base version with fairly simple regex:

```r
mystring <- "-x+2y+z=-1; x-3y-2z=-1; 3x-y-z=4"
equations <- strsplit(mystring, '; ')[[1]]    # split equations
coefs <- strsplit(equations, '[xyz=]+')    # split into list of vectors of coefficients

# iterate over coefficients, clean, and simplify
Ab <- t(sapply(coefs, function(x){
    missing1 <- !grepl('\\d', x);    # detect coefficients with no numbers
    x[missing1] <- paste0(x[missing1], '1');    # paste ones on those
    as.numeric(x)    # coerce from strings (substitute `as.integer` if suitable)
}))

Ab
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]   -1    2    1   -1
#> [2,]    1   -3   -2   -1
#> [3,]    3   -1   -1    4

A <- Ab[, 1:3]
b <- Ab[, 4, drop = FALSE]

A
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]   -1    2    1
#> [2,]    1   -3   -2
#> [3,]    3   -1   -1

b
#>      [,1]
#> [1,]   -1
#> [2,]   -1
#> [3,]    4

solve(A, b)
#>      [,1]
#> [1,]    2
#> [2,]   -1
#> [3,]    3
```

Use `do.call(cbind, lapply(...))` instead of `t(sapply(...))` if you like. Note that the simplicity of the regex are dependent on the regularity of the equations; you'll need a more robust solution if terms are out of order or missing.

Answer (score 2):

Already solved, but I just wanted to post mine too

```
my_string <- "-x+2y+z=-1; x-3y-2z=-1; 3x-y-z=4"
split <- strsplit(strsplit(my_string, ";")[[1]], "=")
right <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split, function(x) as.numeric(x[[2]])))
left <- lapply(split, function(x) x[[1]])
left <- do.call(rbind, lapply(left, function(x) {
  eq_fs = unlist(strsplit(x, "\\W")); eq_fs = eq_fs[eq_fs != ""]
  eq_ss = unlist(strsplit(x, "\\w"))
  eq_ss = eq_ss[c(T, eq_ss[2:length(eq_ss)] != "")]
  idx = grepl("\\d", eq_fs)
  nums = rep(1, length(eq_fs))
  nums[idx] = gsub(".*?(\\d).*", "\\1", eq_fs[idx], perl = TRUE)
  nums = as.numeric(nums) * as.numeric(paste0(eq_ss, 1))
  return(nums)
}))
```